# Exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect to a mysql database by using this simple code.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class OdbcAccessConnection_1 {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver") ;
    // Connect with a url string
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/books","root","1234");
      System.out.println("Connection ok.");
      con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

All it does is tell me if the connection is working. There is no problem with my database and this code/connection work on netbeans. The StackTrace i am getting is -

```
the java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/books
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at OdbcAccessConnection_1.main(OdbcAccessConnection_1.java:13)
```

I am working on 64 bit windows 7 and using 5.1 versions of the Connector/ODBC driver 64 bit. On the ODBC all seems to connect and the test was successful. But when i run the code i get the stack trace above. I am missing something very simple so any input and help would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you:)

Comment: use the [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Comment: Did you add the dependency jar to your project?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but I assume that you run MySQL on "localhost" prior to executing the code above on the same machine, using the standard MySQL port 3306, with the root user having the password noted above, and that your MySQL instance has a database called "books"?  Have you tested connecting locally to the MySQL instance using a standard program such as SQLYog to confirm the connection works?

Comment: No this is not jar dependent. I have gotten this working on netbeans using Connector/J. I want to connect to mysql through the ODBC driver, what we use to do before IDE's came out.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for input. yes my database is running on localhost 3306 and is calling a database called books and every looks like it is running ok, just my program cant find database 'books'. What benefit would downloading SQLYog give me?

Comment: SQLYog, or any other UI program to connect to your MySQL database, can be used just to check that the database exists, is up and running, can be logged into with the credentials you provide, and has the structure/data you expect.  Again, it's not an answer to your question - just a sanity check.  It seems, though, that you're trying to use ODBC, not a direct JDBC connection, so I don't think a JDBC connection string applies (as JB Nizet says in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

Go to Run menu in netbeans or whatever IDE you are using 
=>Set Project Configuration then Customize.Then choose the Libraries on left dropdown menu
Add your appropriate driver file either jar or folder.
Click OK.

Comment: Dude heckkkk ya that saved me!

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/books` is a URL that you use to connect to MySQL directly, using the MySQL JDBC driver. The URL used by the JDBC/ODBC driver is different (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html).

The usage of this JDBC/ODBC bridge is discouraged, and should only be used to access a database that doesn't provide any JDBC driver. This is not the case of MySQL. Use [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), their JDBC driver. Once you have this driver in your classpath, you can use the URL you're currently using, and remove the JDBC/ODBC driver from your classpath (and its loading from your code).

Answer (score 0):

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books","root","1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error creeped on me because I forgot to add the ***Class.forName*** line. The mysql driver jar was on the classpath but no one implicitly loads the driver class, so the session factory can't find any driver classes loaded. Thus the purpose of this line.

In your case, you're loading the wrong thing. It should be ***Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")*** if you intend to use it with a ***jdbc:mysql://*** connection.

Answer (score 0):

best solution bhai logo -:

go to JCreator configure menu then click to options then JDK profiles then double click to whatever the version u r using automatically mention there then click to add archive then go to that path  -> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Tools for 5.0\java\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar press ok.